# Error stopping me from opening Xenko editor

Tags: xenko

I have just recently downloaded the [Xenko game engine](https://xenko.com).

The error is here:

`[C:\Users\bigki\Documents\Xenko Projects\MyGame5\MyGame5.sln.metaproj(0,0)]: Error:The specified solution configuration "Debug|HPD" is invalid. Please specify a valid solution configuration using the Configuration and Platform properties (e.g. MSBuild.exe Solution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU") or leave those properties blank to use the default solution configuration.`

*This error stops me from even opening the editor.*


I have *Visual Studio 2019* installed. I have tried reinstalling Xenko, to no avail.
Anyone got a solution to this error? I cannot seem to find an answer anywhere (i.e **Xenko Forums**, **StackOverflow**, **this website**).

Comment: Sounds like the same symptoms as this issue: https://github.com/xenko3d/xenko/issues/117

Comment: I am trying to download 3.1 right now.